# Сбрасываеться css после создания эллементов prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Проблема в следующем, я получаю данные с бд при помощи json и размещаю их на странице в таблицу построчно с помощью prepend jquery. В этой таблице по нажатию клавиши пользователем к столбцам применяется background css но после обновления данных тем же prepend background сбрасывается.

```js
function send(a) {
  post();
  $(".kolonka" + a).css("background", "#a6b1c1");
}


function post() {

  $("#information").prepend("<tr>" + "<td class=kolonka1>" + obj.iavto + "</td>" +
    "<td class=kolonka2 >" + obj.ikuzova + "</td>" + "<td class=kolonka3>" + obj.idvigatela + "</td>" +
    "<td class=kolonka4>" + obj.icveta + "</td>" + "<td class=kolonka5>" + obj.isalona + "</td>" + "</tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><button onclick="send(1)">ID Автомобиля</button></th>
      <th><button onclick="send(2)">ID Кузова</button></th>
      <th><button onclick="send(3)">ID Двигателя</button></th>
      <th><button onclick="send(4)">ID Цвета</button></th>
      <th><button onclick="send(5)">ID Салона</button></th>
      <th><input id="filter"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="information">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос, но ощущение, что проблема в том, что ajax запрос - асинхронный процесс, то есть он отрабатывает позже, чем то что стоит за ним, соответственно у вас сначала применяется бекграунд, потом отрабатывает пост и добавляются новые элемент к которым уже бекграунд не применяется. Сложно понять без полного кода верно ли мое предположение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал @MedvedevDev, проблема именно в том, что ajax асинхронные. И в моём случае сначала применялся `background`, потом данные удалялись и вставлялись другие, соответственно `bacкground` не работал.